# Ipad, Webkit Animation Issue

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, dom-events

in Ipad web page, there are few images have fade out effect, added by Webkit animation.

However, when I am touching the image to fire fade out function, animation is blinking for no reason. Any help will be much appreciated to stop blinking effect.

Answer (score 0):

try the css `yourimg {-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);}`

Comment: @maxhawkins: Thank you for the notice! Just in case, you know you can edit too right? It will have to be approved but it helps a lot anyway! Thanks again!